# find max. leaf nodes of a binary tree

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

```
       50
     /    \ 
   25      75
  /  \     / \
 15  27   62  79  

depth = 3
total nodes = 7
max leaf nodes = 4
```

```
       50
     /    \ 
   25      75
  /  \     / \
 15  27   62  79  
 _    _   _    _ 
 1    1   1    1  = 4
```

in a case where the Tree is full this will find the total amount of leaf nodes, but if the tree is not full and only the depth of the tree is known how can i know the max. leaf nodes in that tree?

```js
// if the tree is full
function total_leafs_nodes(node, level, mxlevel)
  {
      if (node == null) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
          return 1;

      else if (level == mxlevel)
      {
          return 1;
      }
      return (total_leafs_nodes(node.left, level + 1, mxlevel)
      + total_leafs_nodes(node.right, level + 1, mxlevel));
  }
```

Comment: There is no need to know the depth of the tree. You just go down until there is no child no more (aka leaf node). That node has the value 1. In every other case you recurse into the children and add the newly found leaf nodes to your current amount. You count missing nodes as 1 (should be 0) and also if you reach the max level (should be an error)

Comment: Your question is confusing because you're asking the _max. leaf nodes_ of a tree that is not fully populated.  I was expecting you to ask for the _number of leaf nodes_.    What does _max_ have to do with it?  What is the _max_ condition?  Fully populated?  If so, a fully populated binary tree of depth _n_ always has _2 ^ (n-1)_ leaf nodes.  Also, if node == null, you should return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a max number of child nodes that every node can have, then you can apply the following :

Let d equal the depth, m the number of max child nodes per node, and n the number of possible nodes, then...

```
n = m ^ (d - 1)
```